# Swift Collection extension: pick every other item

Tags: swift, dictionary, collections

I have written the following extension for Collection in Swift that returns a new Collection of every other element from a starting index.

```
extension Collection {
    func everyOtherElement(from theIndex: Int = 0) -> [Element]  {
        if theIndex >= self.count { return self as! [Element] }

        let start = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: theIndex)
        let end = self.endIndex
        var everyOther = [Element]()
        var iter = start

        while iter != end {
            everyOther.append(self[iter])
            let next = index(after: iter)
            if next == end { break }
            iter = index(after: next)
        }       
                 return everyOther
        }
}
```

There are probably ways to improve the code but my issue is when the Collection is a Dictionary. The extension works but returns an Array of Tuples [(key: key, value: value)]
I would like the extension to return a Dictionary.

I have tried Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValuesMethod) which works fine once applied to the return of the everyOtherElement method but I can't seem to find a way to make it so directly.

```
var myDictionary =  ["EN" : "Cheers", "SV" : "Skåll", "ES" : "Salud" ].everyOtherElement()
// returns [(key: "EN", value: "Cheers"),(key: "ES", value: "Salud")]

Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: myDictionary.map { ($0.key, $0.value)})
// returns ["EN" : "Cheers", "ES" : "Salud" ]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your function does do different things. You fast forward to a given index, and then you drop every other item. Neither part makes sense in the context of a dictionary, which has undefined ordering.

Comment: `self as! [Element]` You can’t force cast all collections into an array of elements. A String it is not equal to an `Array<Characters>`

Comment: You are explicitly returning an array

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to reply!!! I am indeed returning an array `[Element]` because I did not find any other way to compile. Hence my original question: in other words, how can I change the code so that it also works for a Dictionary, if possible of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have mentioned a Dictionary is an unordered collection. If you would like to return a Dictionary you can simply extend dictionary and filter every other element. Note that there is no guarantee that the dictionary will keep the order that the key value pairs were enterer. That being said you can accomplish what you want as follow:

```
extension Dictionary {
    var everyOtherElements: Dictionary {
        var bool = true
        return filter { _ in
            defer { bool = !bool }
            return bool
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let dict =  ["EN" : "Cheers", "SV" : "Skåll", "ES" : "Salud" ]
// returns [(key: "EN",
let everyOtherElements = dict.everyOtherElements  // ["ES": "Salud", "SV": "Skåll"]
```

Regarding your comment

> I understand from your reply that I can't extend all collection with
>   the same code, I need to break it down per type?

You don't need to extend every single element type, you can for instance extend `RangeReplaceableCollection` protocol and return `Self` which will englobe `String`s as well:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection  {
    mutating func removeEvenIndexElements() {
        var bool = true
        removeAll { _ in
            defer { bool = !bool }
            return bool
        }
    }
    mutating func removeOddIndexElements() {
        var bool = false
        removeAll { _ in
            defer { bool = !bool }
            return bool
        }
    }
    func evenIndexElements() -> Self {
        var bool = true
        return filter { _ in
            defer { bool = !bool }
            return bool
        }
    }
    func oddIndexElements() -> Self {
        var bool = false
        return filter { _ in
            defer { bool = !bool }
            return bool
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
alphabet.removeEvenIndexElements()
alphabet   // "bdfhjlnprtvxz"

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
arr.removeOddIndexElements()
arr        //  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks Leo! I understand from your reply that I can't extend all collection with the same code, I need to break it down per type (?).